# How to explain the &env example in book <Clojure Programming>

Tags: clojure

There's an example in the book (P252), it's about the &env in macro, I just don't understand how to get the result`{x 1, y 2}`

```
(defmacro spy-env []
  (let [ks (keys &env)]
    `(prn (zipmap '~ks [~@ks]))))

(let [x 1 y 2]
  (spy-env)
  (+ x y))
; {x 1, y 2}
;= 3
```

I tried in the REPL like this:

```
user=> (defmacro spy-env [] (let [ks (keys &env)] `(prn ~@(keys &env))))
#'user/spy-env
user=> (let [x 1 y 2] (spy-env))
2 1
```

It's wried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the macro would be a great way for you to see how it works, but unfortunately `macroexpand-1` doesn't convey the right bindings for `&env`. This example:

```
 (let [x 1 y 2] (spy-env))
```

Actually expands out to:

```
 (let [x 1 y 2] (prn (zipmap '(x y) [x y])))
```

Do you get it? Within the first sequence, `x` and `y` are not evaluated, but within the second, they are. So it zips the symbols to whatever they evaluate to. Within that `let` block, `(zipmap '(x y) [x y])` evaluates to `{x 1 y 2}`.

Comment: I think the &env is like this {x 1 y 2}, so (keys &env) is (x y), x and y are binded to 1 and 2.So [~@ks] is just [x y]([1 2]). Right?

Answer (score 1):

a) If you try the code of the book it does output the right value

```
        user=> (defmacro spy-env []
        #_=>   (let [ks (keys &env)]
        #_=>     `(prn (zipmap '~ks [~@ks]))))
        #'user/spy-env
        user=> (let [x 1 y 2] (spy-env))
        {x 1, y 2}
        nil
        user=> (let [x 1 y 2]
        #_=>   (spy-env)
        #_=>   (+ x y))
        {x 1, y 2}
        3
```

b) now your code is different

initial code :

```
    `(prn (zipmap '~ks [~@ks]))
```

vs

```
    `(prn ~@(keys &env))
```

with actually @(keys &env) being equal to @ks